# stylesheet from plugin not loading

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ruby-on-rails, ruby

Im using ruby on rails and I'm trying to link the stylesheet from a js plugin in my page but rails cant find the file.I would normally put the css file into the `assets/stylesheet` folder and then call it with a `stylesheet_tag` but I can do that because the css file comes in a folder with other important files for the plugin, therefore the css has specific paths (within the folder) defined for those other files.

I put the folder in `vendor/assets` and I'm calling it like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="vendor/assets/lightcase/src/css/lightcase.css">
```

I also tried changing the folder location to `app/assets` and calling it like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/assets/lightcase/src/css/lightcase.css">
```

this is how the folder in organized

```
lightcase
   |
   |--- bower.json
   |--- changelog.txt
   |--- package.json
   |--- src
   |     |---css
   |     |    |---lightcase.css
   |     |
   |     |---js
   |     |    |---lightcase.js 
   |     |
   |     |---fonts
   |     |    |--- other needed files...
   |     |
   |     |---scss
   |          |--- other needed files....
   |
   |---vendor
         |---other needed files...
```

Thank you for the help

Comment: You don't actually need to include a stylesheet or script tag in your view, just put the files in the corresponding assets/stylesheets or assets/javascripts and it will be available automatically.

Comment: yeah I know but those css and js files have paths that call other needed files within lightcase folder